# Is there a design pattern on how to implement field meta information in the user model?

Tags: java, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model

A very basic user model would look something like the following:

```
@Entity
public class User extends Model {

    @Email
    @Required
    public String email;

    (...)
}
```

The user field like the email for example is a single value within the model. Now I want additional information like lastUpdate and settings like whether or not this field should be displayed public or not.

What is the best practice on implementing such field meta information? Is there a design pattern available?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called the Observation Pattern.

[image]

The model allows for dynamic (on-fly) creation of any number of entities with any type of properties without schema changes. However, this flexibility has a price; so storing and searching will be slower and more complex than in a normal table design.